# Stuttering in VLC-Transcode

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, transcode

I'm trying to transcode a working internet stream to something my Dreambox could play.

My current status is that I can play it on my desktop and on Dreambox, however, there is some constant stuttering in the video going on. While the audio is playing fine it seems as if every ~300ms I get to see like three frames, then the last of those frames stands still until the cycle repeats.

Please note that my CPU idles along while this happens. Here's the statement:

```
$ /usr/bin/vlc --no-loop -I dummy http://yourhost.com/your-playlist.m3u8 \
--sout '#transcode{vcodec=mpeg2,acodec=mp2,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8090/vlc.ts}'
```

I also tried `--dash-buffersize=2` (that should be two seconds?), but that didn't help. Using "mpeg1", "mpeg2", "mpgv" or "mp2v" as `vcodec` didn't change anything.

If it's important I use this URL in VLC to play that stream: http://localhost:8090/vlc.ts

I'm guessing that it's either some sync-ing or buffering issue, but I could also be all wrong... So how do I fix this stuttering?